# Sql server while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select query that returns about 10million rows and I then need to insert them into a new table.

I want the performance to be ok so I want to insert them into the new table in batches of 10000.  To give an example i created a simple select query below

```
Insert into new table
 Select top 10000 * from applications
```

But now I need to get the next 10000 rows and insert them. Is there a way to iterate through the million rows to insert them in batches of 10000?? I'm using sql server 2008.

Comment: Is there a unique incrementing counter anywhere in the table?

Comment: You need to write a SP for that.

Comment: If there is any ID column you can just mention the range of that column and select the rows. for example where Columnid>20000 and columnId<30000

Comment: Why are you beating yourself up?  Inserting a million rows shouldn't take that long, unless you have a bunch of triggers and other constraints to deal with.

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to insert all of them at once,rather than trying to iterate through them?

Comment: Hey thanks for the responses.  There cud b more that a million rows as this is just a test server we have. And there is no incremental counter

Comment: (**1**) What does `TOP` without `ORDER BY` mean? (**2**) By going in chunks you're messing up possible optimization options. (**3**) Unless your business logic may dictate to stop loading after certain condition is met, I do not see what makes you think that you'll achieving the efficiency you seem to expect.  Bottom line: modern RDBMS are created for dealing with large databases and as long as their configuration and database indexing is properly done, they should outperform any front-end tricks.

Comment: You should clearly state the reason why you think you should do batch inserts, otherwise all of these answers could be (or will be) wrong, with no way to pick the correct one.  The fastest way to insert (if the situation is okay) is to lock the entire table you're inserting on and insert without firing triggers.  But without more details, who can say what is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

It will probably not be faster by batching it up. Probably the opposite. One statement is the fastest version most of the time. It might just require high amounts of temp space and log. But the fastest measured with the wall-clock.

Reason for that is that SQL Server automatically build a good plan that efficiently batches up all work at once.

To answer your question: The statement as you wrote it produces undefined rows because a table has no order. You should probably add a clustering key like an ID column. That way you can go along the table with a while loop, each time executing the following:

```
INSERT ...
SELECT TOP 10000 *
FROM T
WHERE ID > @lastMaxID
ORDER BY ID
```

Note, that the `ORDER BY` is required for correctness.

Comment: You might add that indexes should/could be dropped prior and recreated after the bulk insert takes place. Depending on the size of the table, this might drastically affect speed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use CTE or While loop to insert like batches

```
;WITH q (n) AS (
   SELECT 1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT n + 1
   FROM   q
   WHERE  n < 10000
)
INSERT INTO table1 
SELECT * FROM q
```

OR

```
DECLARE @batch   INT,
@rowcounter INT,
@maxrowcount    INT

SET @batch   = 10000
SET @rowcounter = 1

SELECT @maxrowcount = max(id) FROM table1 

WHILE @rowcounter <= @maxrowcount
BEGIN   
INSERT INTO table2 (col1)
SELECT col1
FROM table1
WHERE 1 = 1
AND id between @rowcounter and (@rowcounter + @batch)

-- Set the @rowcounter to the next batch start
SET @rowcounter = @rowcounter + @batch + 1;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't batch 10 million records.

If you are batching an insert, use an indexed field to define your batches.

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=10000000)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO yourTable
SELECT *
FROM applications
WHERE ID BETWEEN @intFlag AND @IntFlag + 9999

SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 10000
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can export query to a flat file by bcp and BULK IMPORT it into a table.
BULK IMPORT statement has BATCHSIZE option to limit number of rows.
In your case BATCHSIZE =10000 will work.

There is another option to create SSIS package. Select fast load in OLE DB destination and define 10000 number of rows in “Rows per batch:”. It is probably the easiest solution.